# Writing the Assertion failures to a Text file or Excel Sheet from SOAP UI

Tags: soapui

I have been using SOAP UI Tool to test my web service for Schema Compliance. I would like to export the Schema Compliance failures to an Excel or Text File. Is there a possible way to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer by searching the web a little more. :)

We can use the Groovy script in SOAP UI to achieve this.

```
filePath = 'D:/SchemaComplianceResult/'
def project = testRunner.testCase.testSuite.project
fos = new FileOutputStream( filePath + project.name + '.txt', true )
pw = new PrintWriter( fos )
def runner = project.testSuites['TestSuite 1'].testCases['TestCase 1'].run( null, true )
runner.waitUntilFinished()
def errArray = runner.testCase.getTestSteps()["Request 1"].getAssertionByName("Schema Compliance").getErrors()
pw.println(runner.results[0].getResponseContentAsXml())
pw.println("Schema Compliance Results:")
for(err in errArray){
    pw.println("Line Number:" + err.getLineNumber()+ "Error Message:"  + err.getMessage())
}
pw.close()
fos.close()
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

A more generic way to solve this is to generate reports. SOAPUI allows to generate reports in different formats including Junit style report in the SOAPUI free version. And of-course, this report will show the reason for failure for each test case.